# Android status bar visibility

Tags: android, status

On my tablet (Iconia Tab), only the navigation bar is displayed. 
On my phone (Nexus 5), both navigation bar and status bar are displayed.

How can I know (programmatically) if the status bar is displayed on the device where my application is running ?

Comment: I assume that the reason only one bar is displayed on the Iconia Tab is because Sony has merged the navigation buttons and the status bar [as seen here](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2012/06/acericoniaa210lead01.jpg). So strictly speaking, the status bar is displaying. What's your objective?

Comment: please post the code you are using in manifest to define theme.

Comment: I need to get the screen resolution minus navigation bar and status bar height.

Comment: I don't use any particular theme.